# Hive query "COUNT" returns different results

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have an external HIVE table with HBase as underneath storage. When I ran a query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM myTable
 WHERE row_key>='1'
   AND row_key<='100';
```

It returned 0 results.

However, when I ran it with more conditions:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM myTable
 WHERE row_key>='1'
   AND row_key<='100'
   AND is_new = true;
```

It returned 80 results.

How can this be possible that it returns 0 results with less conditions?

Comment: Perhaps the table was empty before and got populated after you ran the first query? What happens if you run the first query again? Is row_key of type string or int?

Comment: I also ran them with reverse order and still got the same results.